# Removing a block without a name

Tags: php, magento, block

The code below is added by an extension. I want to remove this block from my local.xml but block doesn't have an name. Is there any way to remove a block that doesn't have a name ?

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/template" template="survey/surveyScript.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: what do you mean by remove ? If you dont need, you could comment above code

Comment: Is it the only place that the <reference> element is used?

Comment: I didn't wanna comment out the above code because it is not written by me, it belongs to an extension.
And I don't know why it is relevant but yes it is the only place that <reference> is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove it directly from the extension xml as it does not look to be core. if you want to do it correctly you can still ask the developper to add a name to its block for further update and remove it properly when it has a name.

Comment: So there isn't a way to properly remove it, nice to know that I didn't miss anything.
I ended up copying the extension's xml file to my theme's layout folder and comment out the line.

Comment: Too bad though, that `catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml` contains such block. I can't edit the core-file, so I'll have to find a way to remove it